# Ubuntu 12.04: Can't enter console after running update manager

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, x11, nvidia

When I press **Ctrl+Alt+F1**, I got a screen filled with pure dim-orange ( Ubuntu's color ). Neither can I use console nor can I switch back to X. But the system processes seems to be running, I can continue listening to music. Now I have to use the Terminal app, but it has limitations.

A list of what I have done:

- I bought my laptop 1 yrs ago: lenovo Y480, with Intel Core i5( HD4000 ) + NVIDIA GeForce GT 650m
- I installed Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit on my laptop 2 days ago.
- I downloaded nvidia driver, and had it installed. But the driver didn't seem to work, so I removed it afterwards. The uninstall program also had my xorg.conf reset.
- I upgraded the system via the Update Manager, I selected all updates. After the update complete, I had my computer reboot.
- Now, after reboot, I cannot enter the console.

I guess it could be a graphics driver issue. Because after the update, my screen glitches during startup.

What shall I do now ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an issue with Ubuntu, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

If this were your main OS, I would instruct you to edit `xorg.conf` and mess around with various graphics drivers.  But since you just installed 2 days ago, there shouldn't be any harm from wiping Ubuntu and starting over.  Then you can do updates first to see if the graphics driver really is the problem.